# MySQL Inner Join with IN clause

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Is this sentence optimized?

```
select d.id, d.wfid, d.docid , k.keyword, k.value from keywords k
inner join documents d 
where k.document_id in (23,24) AND k.document_id = d.id;
```

I have some ID's via `POST` (23,24) and I need to get the info for only them, so for that I do the `IN`. Here are hardcoded for testing purposes.

I know MySQL parses the sentences and generates a more optimized one. Is there a way to get that sentence so I avoid having mysql optimizing it all the time?

Thanks!

Comment: A result of MySQL's optimization would be a query plan, not another query. A prepared statement can reuse the plan, provided that the connection and the statement handle persist between the calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run these you n see how MySQL rewrite handle them.
**Note the SQL in the show warnings is not always valid SQL syntax**

```
explain extended select d.id, d.wfid, d.docid , k.keyword, k.value from keywords k
inner join documents d 
where k.document_id in (23,24) AND k.document_id = d.id;
show warnings;
```

Answer (score 2):

In all database engines, queries get parsed into an execution plan that tells the engine how to efficiently run the query given the indexes, structures, and data in the given tables.  Once it is done once, the engine can reuse a plan for the SAME query.

If you replace 23,24, with a paramter then the engine will treat all queries as the same even if the value of the parameter changes.  Normally this is a good thing but can cause issues.  Search parameter sniffing on google if you run into problems.  Otherwise the sql engine won't optimize the query more then once as long as it stores the plan (usually until a restart of the server or if the plan gets dropped due to unuse).

Answer (score 1):

you missed ON clause , it should be like that

```
   select d.id, d.wfid, d.docid , k.keyword, k.value from keywords k
   inner join documents d  ON k.document_id = d.id
   where k.document_id in (23,24)  ;
```